# Creating an array from values in XML

Tags: asp-classic

I want to get values from an XML file. How can I make array of the values in `m1`, `m2` and `m3`?. How can do this?

Here is the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<language> 
    <menus>
        <m1>HomePage</m1>
        <m2>Contact</m2>
        <m3>About Us</m3>
    </menus>
</language>
```

Here's is the ASP code I have:

```
Set Menus = xmlDoc.selectNodes("//language/menus/*" )           
MenuCount = Menus.length
For Each entry in Menus   
    If entry.tagName = "m1" Then 
        m1 = entry.text 
    elseif entry.tagName="m2" then 
        m2 = entry.text 
    elseif entry.tagName="m3" then 
        m3 = entry.text 
    End If   
Next
```

Comment: Given your code, `Menus` will already be an array? I'm confused as to what you're trying to do here.

Answer (score 1):

First I'm compeled to point out that the xml structure presented is poor.  If each element inside `<menus>` represents a  menu then all elements ought to have the same tag name such as `<menu>`.  The use of 1, 2 and 3 suffix indicates the xml designer is confused as to the difference between an *identifier* and a *value*.  If those values are important (i.e., the ordinal position with in the document can not be relied on) then those values should be included as an attribute:-

```
<menus>
    <menu position="1">HomePage</menu>  
    <menu position="2">Contact</menu>  
    <menu position="3">About Us</menu>  
</menus>
```

As to putting them in an array your code seems pretty close but here you go.

```
Dim menuNodes: Set menuNodes= xmlDoc.selectNodes("/language/menus/menu" )                     
Redim menus(menuNodes.length - 1)
Dim i : i = 0          
For Each menuNode in menu
    menus(i) = menu.Text
    i = i + 1
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that your current ASP code doesn't work? One method for obtaining values from XML file and using them within ASP is shown below;

```
<%
Dim menuItems 'Array of menu items

Set objHTTP = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP")
objHTTP.open "GET","http://yourxmlfeed.xml",false
objHTTP.send
XMLData = objHTTP.responseText

' this code takes the raw RSSFeed and loads it into an XML Object
Set xmlFeed = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DomDocument.4.0")
xmlFeed.async = false
xmlFeed.LoadXml(XMLData)
Set objHTTP = Nothing

Set objItems = xmlFeed.getElementsByTagName("menus")

Set xmlFeed = Nothing

' loop over all the items in the XML Feed
For x = 0 to objItems.length - 1
    Set objItem = objItems.item(x)
    For Each objChild in objItem.childNodes
        menuItems = menuItems & objChild.text & ","
    Next
Next

response.write DeleteLastComma(menuItems) 'menuItems is your array of menu items

Function DeleteLastComma
    ...function to remove last comma off array
End Function
%>
```